# Miniature heater with more-or-less constant temperature. Need tip on element

Tags: resistors, heat, heat-protection

I'm a software engineer with very basic knowledge of electronics. 
I have a project in which I want to make a small (cylinder of length about 100-150mm and diameter 20-30mm), localized heater that stays at an absolute temperature of about 50-60ºC.

I researched beforehand, but I'm not sure I understand everything I've found.
Would a thermal cutoff work? I know I could also use a resistor, but doesn't the temperature produced vary depending on the ambient air temperature?

Basically, my question is how can I control the max temperature of the heating element with the smallest possible solution?

Comment: So what type of power do you have.  Only AC?  12V DC?  (etc.)  Then you have to determine how much power you will need.  Is this going to always be in a room temperature environment?  Or will it also go outside, Winter nights at Yellowknife?  You might want to do some testing first.  Do you have any electronics there?  A bench type power supply?  To determine the power you could try just a resistive heater and manual control.  I like these for simple heating, http://www.vishay.com/docs/31806/tmc.pdf  25 ohms and 25 watts is a nice number.  (That's 1 amp and 25 Volts) I like the PTC idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PTC heating element like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/PTC-Heating-Element-80-12VDC-Consistant-Temperature-Ceramic-Heater-Thermostatic-/181407631826?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a3cbcc9d2). They come in all sizes and shapes, including flat flexible ones. The best thing about them is that they are self-stabilizing - temperature increases their resistance and therefore causes negative feedback.

Comment: I like this idea, if the power/ voltage works out.  Have you every done this?  What sort of regulation do you get?  (say for a 10 C change in the environment.)

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this would be with a temperature sensor and a close-loop control. It could be a PID control, proportional or something else.

The heater wattage would be chosen in order to allow the operating temperature to be held easily under worst case conditions (low ambient, high heat loss etc.). Obviously it cannot cool the cylinder so if the ambient got close to 50°C it might not be able to maintain the temperature constant

Since your temperature is within the normal operating environment for electronics, the controller and heater could be contained within the cylinder and power could be supplied.

There are other ways such as bimetal (Klixon) thermostats and so on, and +/-5°C is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could use... a nichrome wire as your heating element, and a tiny thermistor to detect the temperature, and a tiny comparator with a tiny 10-turn trimpot to adjust the temperature, with a power MOSFET to switch the nichrome wire on & off. How accurate does the temperature need to be? Only +/-5°C @ 55°C?

Comment: yes, +-5ºC would be all I need

Comment: @user3317472... 5% temperature regulation should be pretty easy... and the nichrome would be wound in a coil around the inside of your cylinder for even heat distribution. If the external diameter of the cylinder is immaterial, it could be insulated, too, for even greater temperature stability. Otherwise, try to make the cylinder of something that at least won't instantly dump your heat to the world around it. Avoid alumin(i)um, for example, or copper. Cardboard would be **far** better thermally, or most plastics - especially if foamed.